# IE11 position fixed has wrong size

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

Why does IE11 set a wrong size for a fixed positioned element? When his parent has a relative position with exactly defined size with a border-radius and hidden overflow, then the fixed element takes the size of his parent and not its own.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de-CH" lang="de-CH">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Fixed Test</title>
    <style>
    div {
      position:         relative;
      overflow:         hidden;
      min-height:       100px;
      width:            200px;
      border-radius:    5px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    .fixed {
      position:         fixed;
      top:              0;
      left:             0;
      height:           100%;
      width:            100%;
      z-index:          1000;
      background-color: red;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><span onclick="this.className='fixed'">click me</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For reference, [here's a JSFiddle of the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/bb65S/).

Answer (score 1):

When I compared this behavior to Chrome, the key here seems to be `overflow: hidden`. There could be something specific about this in the spec, but I think IE might be in the right here, at least partially. When I tried, the fixed span took the width and height of the whole viewport, but was masked by its containing div's overflow attribute - removing that made the whole screen red.

However, it still turned the upper left corner into a straightedge, which seems to be incorrect.